# bootstrap fixed navbar is hiding slider content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, slider, navbar, nav

I can't figure out how to get the carousel to not hide behind the fixed navbar.

I have tried a few things but I always get lost.

I want the navbar fixed to the top if possible. View the page:

http://www.pegasusbus.com/ebrochure/

Can anyone help me? I am new to all this but a quick learner.

Thank you!

Comment: first validate your code and fix all of the errors and it may work https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0):

add `<br>` after your top navigation. It works for me.